# New line return in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Im creating a report based on **crystal report**.. I'm wondering how can i return a **new line** like for example im a field which is bound to a a datatable where in if the number of text reach the maximum width of the field it would carry to the next line?.

Like if i had a text that is "**Representation and other incidental allowances**" since it exceeds the width of my field , i want to display like below:

"**Representation and other

incidental allowances**"

Hope someone could help me!.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campagnolo_1 says you will need a formula, but I can assure you a formula is not necessary.  All you need to do is place your column where you want it, give it the width you want, and right click on the field, select "Format Text", go to the tab labelled "Common" and check the box next to "Can Grow".  To the right of this option, you will be able to select how many lines this field can 'grow', in other words, this is how many additional lines the field will use to display your text.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a formula in the "Can Grow" option under "Format Field" (right-click on field). You will have to specify after how many characters you'll want the new line, so that could be tricky if your text changes.